# brushless motor speed control

Tags: gpio, pwm

I have successfully been able to turn the motors through the code pasted (found online). I am trying to adapt the code for a speed control, but it seems that the speed only goes to 100%, I have tried to create incriments and set mymotor.setW(30) and the motor does not spin, it only works at mymotor.setW(40).

link to download the code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1tqdxkkh6mkk4a/motor_test.py?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ljbbxrvzshus25/motor.py?dl=0

I want to make the motors increase incrementally like with the DC motor:

clockwise()

while True:

cmd = raw_input("Command, f/r 0..9, E.g. f5 :")

direction = cmd[0]

if direction == "f":

clockwise()

else:

counter_clockwise()

speed = int(cmd[1]) * 11

set("duty", str(speed))

Comment: Please add a link to motor.py code

Comment: added link to dropbox download

Comment: not this file. I'm asking for motor.py file. The file which you are using by running: from motor import motor

Comment: added both https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ljbbxrvzshus25/motor.py?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You normally control an ESC by sending servo pulses, i.e. 1000µs to stop, 1500µs half-throttle, 2000µs full-throttle.

I suggest you send servo pulses.

Comment: sorry if i sound daft, but how can i edit that on this script? I have looked at others and tried to run the code, but it didnt work..

Comment: I'd completely forget your script for the time being and establish if your ESC will respond to normal servo pulses.  You have given no details of the ESC or of the method you are currently using to drive the ESC (the hidden motor.py module).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ljbbxrvzshus25/motor.py?dl=0 

this was the other file in the folder i downloaded, The ESC im using is a TALON 15 castle 16V

Comment: Okay, that uses RPIO which sends servo pulses.  Did you write motor,py or is it something you come across?

Comment: its something I came across - which is why i am unsure on how to edit it to control the speed incrementally

Comment: Can't help with that.  motor.py is odd.  It mentions odd units.  I suggest you have a look at servoblaster or my [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) to drive servos.

Comment: yeah its a bit weird. Ok i will have a look, will servoblaster/pigpio require additional hardware?

Comment: No, no additional hardware required.  They work in the same way as RPIO but (to my mind) have a simpler servo interface, you just specify the pulse width.

Comment: ok awesome, ill check it out. If you have any recommended links for brushless motor control using servoblaster/pigpio would be hugely appreciated. But thank you for the advise.